# Trying to add a column that assigns to each User ID a Quadrant

Tags: sql

Here is my current

[image: Database]

I'm trying to add a column that assigns each user ID to a Quadrant based upon their Progress relative to all other users for that *Day*. (25th, 50th, 75th, 90th, and 99th percentiles)

For example, the I would like to

Here is the current Query, though I'm not sure how helpful it will be, as it contains a few joins

```
SELECT Day, user_id, progress, Revenue, users
FROM Unlock_Progress
INNER JOIN Daily_Revenue  USING(user_id, DAY)
LEFT JOIN DAU  USING (Day)
ORDER BY Day, user_id
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a database tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a window function.  You don't specify the exact logic you want to use, but the following should do what you want or be easily modifiable to your specific needs:

```
SELECT udd.*,
       (CASE WHEN seqnum < 0.25 * cnt THEN 0
             WHEN seqnum < 0.50 * cnt THEN 25
             WHEN seqnum < 0.75 * cnt THEN 50
             WHEN seqnum < 0.99 * cnt THEN 75
             ELSE 99
        END) as percentile_group
FROM (SELECT Day, user_id, progress, Revenue, users,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Day ORDER BY Revenue) as seqnum,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Day) as cnt
      FROM Unlock_Progress u JOIN
           Daily_Revenue dr
           USING (user_id, DAY) LEFT JOIN
           DAU 
           USING (Day)
      ) udd
ORDER BY Day, user_id
```